# MySQL Avoid using the same IF statement in select?

Tags: mysql

Here's my code

```
SELECT
IF(or_opp.has_something = 1, metric.a, NULL) as a,
IF(or_opp.has_something = 1, metric.b, NULL) as b,
IF(or_opp.has_something = 1, metric.c, NULL) as c,
IF(or_opp.has_something = 1, metric.d, NULL) as d,
```

Is there a way of writing this so I only have to check if `or_opp.has_something` once?

edit: (for performance reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just do

```
SELECT
or_opp.has_something as test,
metric.a as a,
metric.b as b,
metric.c as c,
metric.d as d,
```

Then in your scripting language (I suppose PHP), when fetching rows:

```
if ($row['test'] != 1)
{
  // consider that a, b, c, d are NULL
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think this makes things even more of a mess :P

Answer (score 0):

Have I miss understood the problem, or couldn't you just put it in the WHERE clause and print a,b,c,d in your SELECT?

Perhaps post the whole query.

Comment: I can't use a `WHERE`, I need NULL values returned if it's not 1. And I can't use a `LEFT JOIN`, because I need to check specific fields, not the entire record.

Comment: Without seeing the relationships between the tables it is hard to provide a solution.